# How can I change the button text of a custom widget?

Tags: filters, widgets

We had a theme developed that has a custom widget class.

```
class ams_button_widget extends WP_Widget {
...
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) { 
        $btn_text = apply_filters( 'button_text', $instance[ 'button_text' ] );
        $btn_link = apply_filters( 'button_link', $instance[ 'button_link' ] );
        $btn_color_class = apply_filters( 'button_color_class', $instance[ 'button_color_class' ] );

        if( isset( $args[ 'before_widget' ] )) { echo $args['before_widget']; }

        if( isset( $btn_text ) && !empty( $btn_text )) { 
            if( isset( $args[ 'before_button_text' ] )) { echo $args[ 'before_button_text' ]; }
?>
            <a href="<?php echo $btn_link; ?>" class="button rounded <?php echo $btn_color_class; ?>"><?php echo $btn_text; ?></a>
            <?php
            if( isset( $args['after_button_text'] )) { echo $args[ 'after_button_text' ]; }
            if( isset( $args['after_widget'] )) { echo $args[ 'after_widget' ]; }
        } // End if
...
```

We have two instances of the `Button Widget` in the `Top Bar Widgets` of the theme, but the one I need to modify is:

```
<section id="ams_button_widget-2" class="widget ams_button_widget"> <a href="/help-center/download-update/" class="button rounded yellow">Download  Latest Update</a></section>
```

I have been searching and reading through WordPress codex, trying to find an exmaple of what I'm needing to do: append the value of a variable to the `btn_text`.

In the `Widgets` section, this particular `btn_text` is set to [and always will be] `Download Latest Update`. I have a function that collects some version information that I want to append after the default `btn_text`, ie. `Download Latest Update **v1.0.11(2019)**`, but am not having any luck.

Do I modify the class or – as would seem more appropriate – create a function in my `functions.php` that handles it, and if so, can someone offer some explanation?

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Where is your function that collects version information?

Comment: @aton The function that collects this is in the ```functions.php``` file which includes the `/library/custom-widgets.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the `Widgets` section, this particular `btn_text` is set to
>   [and always will be] `Download Latest Update`. I have a function
>   that collects some version information that I want to append after the
>   default `btn_text`, ie. `Download Latest Update **v1.0.11(2019)**`

The widget has a filter named `button_text` which you could utilize to customize the button text *without having to change the widget `class`*:

```php
$btn_text = apply_filters( 'button_text', $instance[ 'button_text' ] );
```

### Option 1: Check if the button text is *exactly* `Download Latest Update`

And if so, then call your function which collects the version information — be sure to change the `version_func` to the correct function name:

```php
add_filter( 'button_text', function( $text ){
    if ( 'Download Latest Update' === $text ) {
        $text .= ' **' . version_func() . '**';
    }

    return $text;
} );
```

*PS: I suggest you to use a **unique** button text to avoid changing (or messing with) other buttons.. or whatever since the filter name is **quite generic** and might be applied by other widget `class`es or other code.*

### Option 2: Enable *shortcodes* inside the button text

1. Enable shortcodes:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'button_text', 'do_shortcode' );
   ```
2. Create a shortcode which *returns* the version information:

   ```php
   add_shortcode( 'my-version-func', function(){
       return version_func(); // I'm assuming that the function does NOT echo anything! :)
   } );
   ```
3. In the button text input (on the Widgets admin page), add `[my-version-func]` wherever you like; e.g. `Download Latest Update **[my-version-func]**`.

### Option 3: Modify the widget `class`/code

*I don't recommend this option*, but anyway, here's an example:

Replace this:

```php
$btn_text = apply_filters( 'button_text', $instance[ 'button_text' ] );
```

with this one:

```php
$btn_text = trim( $instance['button_text'] );
if ( 'Download Latest Update' === $btn_text ) {
    $btn_text .= ' **' . version_func() . '**';
}
$btn_text = apply_filters( 'button_text', $btn_text );
```

Comment: @Greg, I saw your deleted comments, so are you still having problems with customizing the button text? But for options 1 and 2, the code should go into the theme `functions.php` file. And if option 3 doesn't work for you, then perhaps you should post the full widget code - and your custom function which outputs the version information? Alternatively, there is a fourth option.. you could create a custom widget which extends the `ams_button_widget` widget.. but I'd need to see the full widget code.

Comment: I did get it working, thank you! I ended up using Option 2 but had to get the path correct.

Comment: Alright then. I'm glad you got it working. :)